# Debugging/Packaging react-native yields, "Cannot find module 'AsyncStorage'"

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I recently had to reinstall VS Code, up until that debugging just fine, but after the reinstall I've been getting a strange error whenever attempting to start the debugger or starting the packager. I have the launch.json and installed React Native Tools 0.6.17. I'm on node version 8.11.4, react-native version 0.55.4, and VS Code version 1.27.2.

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug in Exponent",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "exponent",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        },
        { 
            "name": "Debug Windows", 
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/launchReactNative.js", 
            "type": "reactnative", 
            "request": "launch", 
            "platform": "windows", 
            "sourceMaps": true, 
            "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.react"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Jest Tests",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}\\node_modules\\jest\\bin\\jest.js",
            "args": [
                "-i"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*"
            ],
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env"
        }
    ]
}
```

Whenever I run the debugger or start the packager, I get the following

```
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'AsyncStorage'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.get AsyncStorage [as AsyncStorage] (e:\repos\Hiu\ReactP4\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\react-native\react-native-implementation.js:71:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (e:\repos\Hiu\ReactP4\node_modules\asyncstorage-down\asyncstorage-core.js:3:43)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (e:\repos\Hiu\ReactP4\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
[Error] Error: Could not start the packager.
```

I've checked the react-native-implementation.js file, and on line 71 there's the line `get AsyncStorage() { return require('AsyncStorage'); },`(sic), which seemingly refers to the AsyncStorage file, located in react-native\Libraries\Storage.

All that to say, why can't it find AsyncStorage, and why is that an issue with packaging?

Comment: Might you have forgotten to import it?

Comment: Good call, but it's not my file, it's all contained in the react-native node_modules folder.

Comment: oh you mean it's a library you've installed that's using `AsyncStorage`? In any case `AsyncStorage` is part of the native `react-native` library fyi if you didn't know which stores local data. If I were you I would try removing my nodes_module file and reinstalling. --> Run `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

Comment: I did, worked like a charm! Funny thing, I had done it half a dozen times, hadn't worked, but hey, seventh time's the charm.